# How can I add a Spark template view instead of ASP.NET template view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I am using the Spark view Engine instead of the default ASP.NET view engine and I'd like to be able to add a 'spark' view instead of a 'ASP.NET' view when adding a new view to the project. I assume this would just be a template of some kind but I can't seem to find it.

for example I want it to generate a view something like this;

```
<use namespace="Business.Core.DomainObjects.Gadget"/>
<use master="application" />

<content:title>Gadgets</content:title>
<div>
</div>
```

instead of this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Get</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC templates are stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Web\MVC\CodeTemplates. You can change them there, but you should copy CodeTemplates folder to your project and change them there.

Here you can read about it: http://aspalliance.com/1813_ASPNET_MVC_10_Release_Candidate_Now_Available.5